# How to send parallel requests from same user in Gatling Scala?

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling

I'm new in Gatling. I want to sent some request(or group of requests) from same user. I want it run in parallel.

Is there ways how to do this?

I already checked methods `atOnceUsers` and others. Also i checked `resources` ([link](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/?#resources:%7E:text=(gzipBody)-,Resources,-%23)), but i think it is a different thing

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you'd need these requests to be fired from the same user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (as of Gatling 3.9.2), Gatling virtual users can only send HTTP in parallel when they are children of a parent request, thanks to `resources`. This feature is used to emulate resources loaded after loading an HTML page.

If you think your use case is not covered and it would make sense for lots of other users, feel free to reach out on the [Gatling Community forum](https://community.gatling.io/) and discuss there.

Comment: I tried again with resources, and it helps, thank you!